# convert a method call with parameters to a Function that takes no parameters

Tags: scala, function, methods

Creating a function from method call that takes no parameters requires below syntax :-

> val d = display _

How to do the same thing for method call with parameters.
Please find below sample code.

```
package paf

/**
  * Created by mogli on 8/27/17.
  */
object PafSample {

  def display(): Unit ={
    println("display is a no argument method")
  }

  def evenOdd(input : Int) : Unit = if(input % 2 == 0) println(s"$input is even")  else println(s"$input is odd")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //This is working
    val d = display _
    executeFunction(d)

    //TODO : convert to a function call that takes no arguments,
    //       so that, it can be passed to executeFunction as parameter

    //val e = evenOdd(3) _
    //executeFunction(e)
  }

  def executeFunction[B](f : () => B) : B = {
    println("executing function")
    f()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work. `executeFunction` is a method taking a function which takes on parameters and returns a `B`. `evenOdd` takes a single parameter of type `Int` and yields `Unit`, meaning `Int => Unit`.

You'll need to accept a parameter:

```
def executeSingleArgFunction[A, B](a: A)(f: A => B): B = {
    f(a)
}
```

And then:

```
executeSingleArgFunction(3)(evenOdd)
```

Comment: val d= display _;  executeSingleArgFunction(())(d) is giving CTE.